# What would I use to write a formula only once and have it work on multiple sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to write a formula once in one sheet and have others call that formula and do calculation in their own sheet. I want to do this because calculations need to be done in 100 other sheets within the same document but I don't want to have to change the formula in every one of those sheets if we decide to modify it.

Comment: Do you mean other sheets within the same document or across different documents?

Comment: Within the same document.

Comment: In Excel to refer to a cell in another sheet you use: `=Sheet1!B7` (for example) but I'm not sure how this helps you in your case.

Comment: Doing that doesn't bring the formula over it brings the value over.

Comment: If you associate your Web Apps and Super User accounts you'll regain ownership of the original question.

Comment: Hi dotLoom, just wondering if you ever found a solution to your problem... I need to do the same thing and have found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand you requirement but perhaps a named range would help you. Take for example:

[image: WA7923 example]

Now name A3 - the default would be `NamedRange1`. This can be used elsewhere in the same sheet or in other sheets in the same document with:

```
=NamedRange1
```

to return `6` wherever entered.

Now say change `+` to `^` in A3 above. Then all those `6` entries will change to `16`.

Answer (score -1):

Excel doesn't have a built-in to return the formula, you will have to use [this user defined](http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/formula.htm#getformula) function.

Comment: Does anything like this exist for Google Docs?

Comment: No, Nothing built in or user defined, you'll have to build a script

Comment: I was trying to build a custom function `=CopyFormula()` but it the scripting API forbids us developers from grabbing data from any cell other than the current active cell when using custom functions, so I doubt this will be possible in Google Docs

Comment: Thanks for trying. How do I use this? http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_range.html#getFormula

Comment: @dotLoom This is what I had came up with, while trying to create that custom formula http://pastebin.com/qVcgBufV

Comment: Does that function work? How do I call it from my spreadsheet?

Comment: Like I said - ` scripting API forbids us developers from grabbing data from any cell other than the current active cell when using custom functions`. I wanted you to enter `=copyFormula` in the cells to which you need to copy the formula but this is not possible via custom function.

Comment: ah ok wasn't sure if that was a new script, thanks for trying!

Comment: How does that scripting work in general? How do you call it from a spreadsheet?

Comment: @DotLoom I'm not very familiar, there are certain trigger items upon which the scripts can be called http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/guide_events.html

Comment: Do you know a way to insert a formula from an outside file or even put it within that script you wrote?